# Grails controller saves the domain item anyways

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-controller

Using Grails 2.3.9

In a controller I do some checks and when failing returning with a custom error response. Here is a code snippet:

```
def update() {
    def instance = Group.get(params.groupId)
    instance.properies = params

    if (instance.hasErrors()) {
        // going through here: instance is not saved
        respond instance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    // do custom checks
    if(checksFailed) {
        // instance is saved anyways :(
        instance.discard()
        response.sendError(response.SC_CONFLICT)
        return
    }

    instance.save flush:true
    // ... respond success
}
```

When the check fails, my error response is returned as I want it. However, the instance gets saved anyways (the `instance.save` is not reached). How can I make Grails/Hibernate know to not save this instance?

Another approach might be to disconnect the instance from the Hibernate session. How would I have to do this in Grails?

Update: in a controller where the domain instance is scaffolded, the `instance.discard()` trick works:

```
def update(Group groupInstance) {
    if (groupInstance.hasErrors()) {
        // going through here: instance is not saved
        respond instance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    // do custom checks
    if(checksFailed) {
        // instance is not saved
        groupInstance.discard()
        response.sendError(response.SC_CONFLICT)
        return
    }

    groupInstance.save flush:true
    // ... respond success
}
```

I find it difficult to understand why it works in one case and not in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is not to use discard() but instead to use transactions and the native transaction features of your database. I would recommend moving the logic into a service (separating your controller flow code and the logic of your application. Example:

```
class GroupService {
   @Transactional
   void updateBook(params) {
       ....
       // do custom checks
       if(checksFailed) {
          status.setRollbackOnly() // rollback transaction        
       }
       else {
           instance.save flush:true
       }
   }
}
```

You can either call `setRollbackOnly` on the transaction status or throw a *runtime* exception.

Note if you use exceptions, they can be expensive so it is best to create a custom exception type say `GroupUpdateException` and override the `fillInStackTrace` to not fill the stack trace which reduces the cost of exception. See [Why is Throwable.fillInStackTrace() method public? Why would someone use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788993/why-is-throwable-fillinstacktrace-method-public-why-would-someone-use-it)

Comment: I'm tending to go with your second advice (using exceptions). However, is there a reason the case in the question does not work? I thought, that would be the way to do it. Thanks for your effort in answering.

Comment: It might be that your additional checks perform queries which cause the updates to be be automatically flushed so the query is consistent, which is why using a transaction is important